# Bootstrap Modal is not working in React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I get an error.
I have added some code and would like to my code to get to know why
its not working.
I can't use react-strap. Please suggest if we can use Bootstrap modal in react.

I get an error.
I have added some code and would like to my code to get to know why
its not working.
I can't use react-strap. Please suggest if we can use Bootstrap modal in react.
Below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
        });
    }
    
    render()
    {
        return (
          <div>
             <div className="bd-example">
                 //Button code
                 <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLive">
                Launch demo modal</button>

              //Modal code
              <div className="modal" id="exampleModalLive" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
              <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Modal;
```

Comment: It's is better to not add `jquery` in react project. Post your code so that we can help.

Comment: Suggest you to try this - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Comment: I can't use react-strap in my work. As it is not own by Bootstrap.

Comment: in that case you need to use jquery using CDN, add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to index.html file.

Comment: Post you code, how you are using modal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include `jquery` and `bootstrap` using `CDN` in `index.html` file which is in `public` folder.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have added `bootstrap.css` file,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hjsn66?file=index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't import bootstrap CSS and js in index.js file.

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

it will work fine after import these CSS and js

Answer (score 0):

install jquery

```
npm install -S jquery
```

import jquery and bootstrap

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```